# CascadingAuthenticationState and NotFoundContent tags not working in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, blazor, blazor-client-side

So I've been following [this tutorial](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/) for implementing authorization/authentication on my blazor client app (asp.net core hosted). Everything worked ok until I started working on client side ("Configuring client-side Blazor" subtitle in [the tutorial](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/)). I've successfully installed Blazored.LocalStorage nuget package. But I'm failing at adding "CascadingAuthenticationState" and "NotFoundContent" components to my App.razor file. The compiler can't see these componnents and asks to add using directives.

Here's the _Imports.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Musical_WebStore_BlazorApp.Client
@using Musical_WebStore_BlazorApp.Client.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
```

Here's the App.razor that's not working (and I'm asking to help me to get it working):

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <NotFoundContent>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </NotFoundContent>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Here's the App.razor that was working (I had it by default):

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Here are the versions of the projects:

> Blazor.Client (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor nuget package): 3.0.0-preview9.19465.2
>
> ASP.NET Core (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Server nuget package): 3.0.0-preview9.19465.2
>
> Shared: .NET Standard 2.0 library

How do I solve this problem? It looks like these components should be available by default. And even if not, I couldnt find the namespace for these components on the internets.

Comment: I guess that <NotFoundContent> is supposed to be a RenderFragment attribute property of the Router Component, but no such attribute exists. Use <NotFound> instead...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` package from NuGet. This package didn't exist at the time I wrote that article. Once you've installed it and added a using to the `_Imports.razor` you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for <CascadingAuthenticationState>. However there's also <NotFoundContent> tag in your tutorial that isn't working for me. Or is it the same as <NotFound> in the App.razor working version in my question?

Comment: It should be `NotFound` rather than `NotFoundContent`